# How can two classes share the same style for reactjs @emotion/styled

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

For my regular html code, I have this:

```
<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```

For the regular CSS, I have this:

```
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px; /* Use half of the width (120/2 = 60), to center the tooltip */
}
```

In my react app using `@emotion/styled`, I have the code

```
const TooltipContainer = styled('div')`
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
`
```

for the `.tooltip` class but how can I implement the `.tooltip .tooltiptext` part?

Based from the tutorial https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use Inheritance of Styled component like below.

// The Button from the last section without the interpolations

```
const Button = styled.button`
  color: palevioletred;
  font-size: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.25em 1em;
  border: 2px solid palevioletred;
  border-radius: 3px;
`;
```

// A new component based on Button, but with some override styles

```
const TomatoButton = styled(Button)`
  color: tomato;
  border-color: tomato;
`;
```

Answer (score -1):

try

'.tooltip, .tooltiptext'

or

'.tooltip .tooltiptext '

Comment: This is the original code. I want it to be in `@emotion/styled` format.